# Python: How to create a C type for loop for a geometrical progression?

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to create a for loop equivalent for:

```
for (int i = n; i > 0; i = i/2){
    //do Something
}
```

Notice the `i = i/2`.

Is there an out of the box Python way to do this in a for without creating a custom generator? Using `xrange` seems to only support (+/-) step values, not division.

Comment: Did you try searching for Python for loop syntax? https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: Also, this is an infinite loop because `i > 0` is always true since you always divide by 2

Comment: @cricket_007 not when it's integer division.

Comment: Looks like it should be a while loop to me... `i = n; while i: i /= 2` (imagine the proper line breaks and indents). `while` loop indicates you want to repeat an unknown number of times. `for` loop indicates you want to repeat a known number of times.

Comment: @cricket_007 syntax for xrange is used for a arithmetic progression (+/- an index) and not a geometrical one. The question was if there is a Python way, except of creating a generator

Comment: I understood what you were going for, so I didn't downvote. The way you asked though, made it seem like you didn't know how to write a basic python for-loop. If you explained what you just said in your question, that may not have happened

Comment: @cricket_007 I will take that in account on next question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer division version let `n = 8`. Halts at `n = 0`.

```
while i > 0:
    print("do something")
    n = n >> 1 # shift right, divide by 2
```

Floating point division let `n = 8.0`. Halts at `n = 5*10^(-324)`

```
while i > 0:
    print("do something")
    n /= 2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i = n
while int(i) > 0:
    i = i / 2
    # do something
```

Comment: or`while i > 0: i = int(i / 2)`

Answer (score 1):

Why not something like:

```
i = n
while i > 0:
    #do something
    i /= 2
```